# Codeigniter 4 - how to show 404 page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

It's a very silly question but I can't handle it :) In Codeigniter 3, I just used show_404() function in any controller to show 404 page. How could I do the same with Codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was looking just now exactly for the same thing.
I found here the solution: [CodeIgniter 4 User Guide - Error Handling](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/errors.html?#pagenotfoundexception)

In your controller, simply write:

```
throw \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException::forPageNotFound();
```

Answer (score 2):

U can try this

```
    <?php
  // Would execute the show404 method of the App\Errors class
    $routes->set404Override('App\Errors::show404');

    // Will display a custom view
    $routes->set404Override(function()
    {
        echo view('my_errors/not_found.html');
    });
```

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#override